# Including static html inside Sharepoint 2010 Master Page

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 with a custom master page. I also have a non-Sharepoint part of the site that has an html file containing content that needs to be on the Sharepoint part of the site as well. I was wondering if it is possible to include the html file inside my master page so whenever the html file is updated, only 1 file needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Page Viewer WebPart?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx

Of course if you place it in the master page, it will have to be a static webpart (no webpart zone)